# terraform null_resource frequently triggers change

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

Using null_resource I attempt to run kubectl apply on a kubernetes manifest. I often find that this applies changed for no given reason. i'm running terraform 0.14.8.

```
data "template_file" "app_crds" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/app_crds.yaml")
}

resource "null_resource" "app_crds_deploy" {
  triggers = {
    manifest_sha1 = sha1(data.template_file.app_crds.rendered)
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f -<<EOF\n${data.template_file.aws_ingress_controller_crds.rendered}\nEOF"
  }

}
```

terraform plan output

```
  # module.system.null_resource.app_crds_deploy must be replaced
-/+ resource "null_resource" "app_crds_deploy" {
      ~ id       = "698690821114034664" -> (known after apply)
      ~ triggers = {
          - "manifest_sha1" = "9a4fc962fe92c4ff04677ac12088a61809626e5a"
        } -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
    }
```

however, this sha is indeed in the state file.

```
[I] ➜ terraform state pull | grep 9a4fc962fe92c4ff04677ac12088a61809626e5a
              "manifest_sha1": "9a4fc962fe92c4ff04677ac12088a61809626e5a"
```

Comment: Is that the full `terraform plan` output? I would expect it to also say something about `data.template_file.app_crds`, since `data.template_file.app_crds.rendered` seems to be yielding "(known after apply)".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `kubernetes_manifest` resource from the `terraform-kubernetes-provider`. Using the provider won't require the host to have `kubectl` installed and will be far more reliable than the `null_resource`, as you are seeing. They have an [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest#example-create-a-kubernetes-custom-resource-definition) specifically for CRDs. Here is the snippet of terraform from that example:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "test-crd" {
  manifest = {
    apiVersion = "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1"
    kind       = "CustomResourceDefinition"

    metadata = {
      name = "testcrds.hashicorp.com"
    }

    spec = {
      group = "hashicorp.com"

      names = {
        kind   = "TestCrd"
        plural = "testcrds"
      }

      scope = "Namespaced"

      versions = [{
        name    = "v1"
        served  = true
        storage = true
        schema = {
          openAPIV3Schema = {
            type = "object"
            properties = {
              data = {
                type = "string"
              }
              refs = {
                type = "number"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

you can keep your k8s yaml template and feed it to the `kubernetes_manifest` with this:

```
data "template_file" "app_crds" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/app_crds.yaml")
}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "test-configmap" {
  manifest = yamldecode(data.template_file.app_crds.rendered)
}
```